# Unable to populate data into jqGrid control, but no errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I'm not sure where I am doing wrong, I am unable to populate data into jqGrid control.

Tried different articles, and verified some video tutorials, but no luck.

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue!

Below is the code in `HomeController`.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult JQGridOrders()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetOrders()
        {
            using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                var ordersList = db.Orders.Select(x => new OrderInfo {
                    OderID = x.OrderID,
                    CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                    OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                    Freight = x.Freight,
                    ShipName = x.ShipName,
                    ShipAddress = x.ShipAddress
                }).ToList();
                return Json(new { rows = ordersList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

My `OrderInfo` class is below

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public int OderID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? Freight { get; set; }
    public string ShipName { get; set; }
    public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the View

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Showing Orders in JQGrid Control"; }
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<link href="~/Content/Theme/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 jQuery.browser = {};
   (function () {
       jQuery.browser.msie = false;
       jQuery.browser.version = 0;
       if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
           jQuery.browser.msie = true;
           jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
       }
   })();
</script>
<script src="~/scripts/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $grid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetOrders", "Home")',
            mtype: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            colModel: [
                { label: 'Order ID', name: 'OrderID' },
                { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID' },
                { label: 'Order Date', name: 'OrderDate' },
                { label: 'Freight', name: 'Freight' },
                { label: 'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName' },
                { label: 'Ship Address', name: 'ShipAddress' }
            ],
            loadonce: true
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: There are no `dataType` option - only `datatype` option. Default `datatype: "xml"` options will be used by default and your JSON data are wrong. The next problem: your don't see any error message. Such behavior could exist depend on version of jqGrid, which you use. Please write always **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop "free jqGrid" fork, which displays error message in your case.

Comment: Additionally to fixing `dataType: 'json'` to `datatype: 'json'` I'd recommend to add `key: true` property in `OrderID` column or/and to add `prmNames: { id: "OrderID" }` jqGrid option and `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "OrderID" }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change return type of action from ActionResult to JsonResult

```
       [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetOrders()
        {
            using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                var ordersList = db.Orders.Select(x => new OrderInfo {
                    OderID = x.OrderID,
                    CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                    OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                    Freight = x.Freight,
                    ShipName = x.ShipName,
                    ShipAddress = x.ShipAddress
                }).ToList();
                return Json(new { rows = ordersList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: No man! In fact, I kept JsonResult as return type in the very beginning. For me, the comedy is that even action method is not hitting...

Answer (score 0):

You should map the elements between `json response` and `colModel` with `jsonmap` and `jsonReader`

- [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data&s[]=jsonreader#jsonreader_as_function) to define the elements
- [jsonmap](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options&s[]=jsonmap) Defines the json mapping for the column in the incoming json string.

Here is the demo and have used some fake data to show the mappings.

```js
$(function () {

 $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('load error: ' + error);
                },
                mtype: 'GET',
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ["Id", "First Name"],
                colModel: [
                         { name: "Id", index: "id",key:true, width: 50, jsonmap: "id" },
                         { name: "First Name", index: "first_name", width: 200, jsonmap: "first_name"}
                ],

                gridview: true,
                jsonReader: { repeatitems:true, root:"data" },
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                width:500,
                height: 200,
                caption: "JSON Example",
            });
            
            
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

<table id="jqGrid"></table>
```

Comment: Tried this technique. Still no output, no console errors

Comment: Could you do a simple `$.ajax` request and see if you get the response from the api?

Comment: Great, I am getting the complete response when I make `$.ajax` request. Hence, where could be the wrong? Why I am not getting data into jqGrid?

Comment: I hope is `#jqGrid` is table in your html

Comment: Also, don't use minifed version, try full version and so it will return the actual error why it is failing to load